# Do variables need to be initialized in a session in tflearn?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tflearn

Maybe this is a stupid question, but I switched from basic TensorFlow recently to tflearn and while I knew little of TensorFlow, I know even less of tflearn as I have just begun to experiment with it. I was able to create a network, train it, and generate a model that achieved a satisfactory metric. I did this all without using a TensorFlow session because a) none of the documentation I was looking at necessarily suggested it and b) I didn't even think to use it.

However, I would like to predict a value for a single input (the model performs regression on images, so I'm trying to get a value for a single image) and now I'm getting an error that the convolutional layers need to be initialized (Specifically "FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value Conv2D/W").

The only thing I've added, though, are two lines:

```
model = Evaluator(network)
model.predict(feed_dict={input_placeholder: image_data})
```

I'm asking this as a general question because my actual code is a bit troublesome to just post here because admittedly I've been very sloppy in writing it. I will mention, however, that even if I start a session and initialize all variables before that second line, then run the line in the session, I get the same error.

Succinctly put, does tflearn require a session if I've not used TensorFlow stuff directly anywhere in my code? If so, does the model need to be trained in the session? And if not, what about those two lines would cause such an error?

I'm hoping it isn't necessary for more code to be posted, but if this isn't a general issue and is actually specific to my code then I can try to format it to be understandable here and then edit the post.

Comment: An advice: That's the issue with the frameworks built on top of TF. They try to write wrappers for wrappers. The problem starts when they try to oversimplify things. And they do. Sometimes too much abstraction makes stuff more difficult. Most TF is already implemented following some wise decisions and guidelines. **All** frameworks built on top of TF require a session, even when they try to hide the session and try to not expose other things. At some point you will need these (not in your case). Better start with officially supported tf.layers. And then decide if you need another wrapper.

Comment: @patwie I believe I do need a wrapper. I started this with base TF but was having a mountain of issues that I just could not get resolved for the life of me, even though I knew exactly what the issues were. I switched to tflearn on a whim and, without changing anything about the model, it worked the first time. It's good to know they do require a session, but does it need to be explicitly created or does tflearn start one itself in the background?